# Error in loading image from external file

Tags: android, imageview

So, I'm trying to load an image that is stored on my SD Card and display it in an Image View.
However, it gives a run-time error.
Here's my Java code.

```
package com.example.cameracapture;

import java.io.File;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class DisplayPage extends ActionBarActivity {

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/DCIM/Camera/image_001.jpg"; 
File imgFile = new File(path);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_page);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }


    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Display);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_page, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_page, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
    }
}
```

Here's my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/stupid_android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Display"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/upload" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also know the error is due to these lines-

```
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Display);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Because, when I remove the above three lines of code, the empty Image View is shown perfectly. Am I calling the image wrong? What should I do to correct it? Perhaps I shouldn't use it in the OnCreate method?

EDIT- Here's my error log

```
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074): Process: com.example.cameracapture, PID: 25074
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cameracapture/com.example.cameracapture.DisplayPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at com.example.cameracapture.DisplayPage.onCreate(DisplayPage.java:41)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
06-10 12:47:02.796: E/AndroidRuntime(25074):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: use this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513112/bitmapfactory-decodefile-and-imageview-strange-thing-in-android

Comment: try this as you dont need to give file path, you can use string path BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);

Comment: @raj- I tried your way too...it still gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the error was due to calling the image in the `OnCreate` Method.

I created a new method, `OnResume`, and called the image there, as follows-

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/DCIM/Camera/image_001.jpg"; 
    File imgFile = new File(path);

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Display);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the image in the `onCreate` is the right way to do it but what I would suggest, since it is a static image is to use the `drawable` resource directory and set the image directly from XML.

So simply place your image in the corresponding drawable directory and then add this to your XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Display"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/upload"
    android:src="@drawable/image_001"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#0000FF" />
```

As a sidenote, you should probably use PNG images.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with uploading the image from the drawable directory. However, I wish to upload it from external memory path.
Maybe, there's a way to transfer the image from the external memory to the drawable folder after running the code?

Comment: I understand what you want to do now, so please disregard my answer in this case:) My other suggestion would be this `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`If not please tell me which one is line 41 in your activity:D

Comment: Moving that code didn't work either.
line 41 is myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Comment: Then you should check your path again, perhaps try to print it to see exactly where you are navigating. From what I see it does not find any image there and therfore doesn't have what bitmap to decode, there is the source of the null pointer exeption

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.
I'm sorry if I sound like a noob (that's probably because I'm a beginner to this), but how do i print the path within the code?

Comment: Just do something like this: `System.out.println("This is the path to your image: "+path);` in your onCreate method, before setting the image:D and check the output of that to be what you expect, i.e. the correct path to your image.

Comment: ah, there it is.
it says
This is the path to your image:
storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/image_001.jpg